How do I fill the gap around a window?

In my quest to make my apartment as bug proof as possible I stumbled on this gap.
Metal framed windows don’t quite seal the gap with the wall.
For the baseboard gap all around the house I used transparent silicone and it worked wonderfully. For the bigger holes I used steel wool and spackle. What about here? Silicone could work too. It will also help with drafts in winter. Or should I use some other sealant?

Those gaps are regularly filled with acrylic latex caulk.

The latex is easily applied then the excess is wiped away with a damp drywall sponge. Clean up is with water unlike silicone.
It is important to understand that sealing or caulking any gaps or openings in the interior, while esthetically appealing, does not prevent bugs from coming in.  (They just look for another opening)  The treatment should begin on the outside of the home.

Thanks! Oh I know that sealing is not all I need. But if I can stop 99% of their ways in it will still cut down on wanderers. I’m in an apartment building so I’m just as big free as the dirtiest person in the building.
Thanks for the answer!
Side question, how do you clean up regular silicone? I just carefully scrape off the excess when still soft. Or scrape off with knife when dry. Is there a proper way?

Proper way is to use mineral sprits when the caulk is still wet. However for most sealing job where there is not a water seal needed the acrylic latex is the product to use. Easy water clean up.
